# To run MySQL on Mac have to export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal

To run mysql on my mac I always have to send this command on terminal:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

insert it into your ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile